# How to call java methods inside javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to call java methods inside java script how can I? and How can i pass the parameters to java method?

This is button code now I want to call java method from validate form.

```
<a class="btn btn-success"  href="./checklist.jsp?a=<%= resumeid%>" title="Offer Letter"   onclick="validate(this)">
  <i class="icon-file icon-white"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: guys i'm stuck  here . My requirement is if once offer-letter sent I want popup box message like "Already sent Do u want to send again" If yes the I want to send.Here while clicking on button I'm passing user ID.

Comment: Just read about the AJAX. then you will find how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to fetch data on button click, try using ajax call and then fetch and do respective operation of the data.

Comment: up-to that I did but. If that record is already exist i want to give conformation if yes then i want to send page to another page and save the entered data in database

Comment: you can redirect the page according to your need. you can use window.location = "path to redirect" and if you are use CRUD Restful api to save in database.

or you can use POST method to save in database and redirect to another page.

Comment: I got by using Ajax. Thank you every one

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that:

- your java code is executed on your server before generating the client's web page
- your javascript code is executed in the client's browser, once the page has been downloaded

As a consequence it doesn't make sense to directly call a server method from your client side javascript.

However you can trigger an AJAX request to the server from your javascript code.

Comment: Thank u. But My requirement is if once offer-letter sent I want popup box message like "Already sent Do u want to send again" If yes the I want to send.Here while clicking on button I'm passing user ID